# wpf Change tabitem header orientation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf **Tabcontrol** with two **TabItem** tabs are placed to **left**.

Now I want to show headers content vertically and adjust tab width to the content.

Something like this.

[image]

I tryed using a Header template rotating the label in it, text were rotated but tab remains it's shape.

[image]

Here my template:

```
<TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="Hola mundo" Margin="15,0">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
```

Some sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TabStripPlacement" Height="200" Width="250" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                     <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                    </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Header="General">
                <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Security" />
            <TabItem Header="Details" />
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Tks, I'm going to take a look into it. Can be this included into a style ?

Comment: Yes, you should have no problem doing that.